# Do these cracks on my tires look bad?

Tags: tires

I know that the picture might not help but I need some help as I don’t know if these cracks look bad. I won’t be able to replace tires for a while so I was wondering if they will be good to drive on freeway a few times in the next two weeks

[image: Picture of car tire with some cracking]

Comment: Cracks are dry rot, replace any tire with cracks.

Answer (score 15):

Your tires are nearly nine years old - a good rule of thumb is to replace tires at 6 years of age. And I'm sorry to say it but they don't look good - the big worry with cracks is the ones you **can't** see. The rubber will be degrading throughout the tire and this can lead to sudden and catastrophic failure when the tire comes apart.

Are they safe to drive? **No.** If it was a matter of a low-speed drive round to get them changed that's one thing, they are less likely to fail under such low stress and if they do you stand a good chance of getting things under control without hurting yourself or others. Freeway driving? No chance - too big a risk IMO.

Comment: IIRC tire cracks will make you fail the MOT test

Comment: @Martin Strictly speaking they are only a fail if the cords are visible or can be seen/reached by inserting a "blunt object" into the crack or holding it open (sometimes the stuff that will get past an MOT is.. concerning!). Can't tell whether the OP's tires would be a fail from just the picture. Quite possibly not relevant though as they mentioned "freeway" which means they likely aren't in the UK.

Comment: @Martin I had the garage phone me about someone else's car when I had my last MOT (same make, model, colour).  They told me that it had passed, as there was enough grip, but that the tyres had perished and should be replaced.  So while yes, it is something that the garage should be able to pick up on, it isn't a MOT fail.

Comment: @Martin What's an MOT test?

Comment: @Deolater MOT is Ministry of Transportation.  It's a British version of a car safety inspection, and much more rigorous than the simple tests in some US states.  More info on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOT_test).

Comment: @JPhi1618 In fact, some US states don't even have a mandatory inspection...

Comment: I didn't even know tires had the date of manufacture stamped into them. Will have to go see how old my own tires are now.

Comment: @RoijanEskor See my answer [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/64367/dry-rot-tire-should-i-replace/64370#64370) for a quick start guide on how to read the dates

Comment: @GalacticCowboy _Some_ US states? I'd guess the _majority_ of US states don't have vehicle inspections. Unfortunately.

Comment: Besides the cracks, those treads look *thin*!

Comment: @FreeMan, [Here is a nice map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_inspection_in_the_United_States) for you that shows states with inspections.  Looks like you are right - seems like most do not.  I know in Texas there is a yearly bill that tries to do away with them, but hasn't passed yet.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Ministry of Transport. Strangely, the test is still called that, even though the government department hasn't used that name since 1970.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Thanks, I thought it might be UK-ish (MO-- is a giveaway), but then I thought commonwealth folks used "tyre" rather than "tire", so I remained unsure.

Comment: @Deolater yep "tyre" is the correct spelling - to my eternal shame as Brit I tend to use American spellings on SE :D